# Gradle transitive dependencies from Task defined in buildSrc

Tags: gradle

I want to make a task accessible from all subprojects in my build. The task ant execution has a dependency to the jaxb-xjc JAR, and the classpath provided to ant must include jaxb-xjc.

My soution:
Create a /buildSrc/build.gradle with a custom configuration for the jaxb-xjc dependency:

```
configurations {
    jaxb
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    jaxb 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.2.4-1'
}
```

Then create the task under /buildSrc that use the classpath in the jaxb configuration:

```
class JaxbTask extends DefaultTask {
...
    @TaskAction
    def main() {
        ...
        ant.taskdef(name: 'xjc', classname: 'com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask', classpath: project.configurations.jaxb.asPath)
        ...
        }
}
```

However, *project.configurations* end up referring to the project *using* the task class, not to the configurations of the /buildSrc/build.gradle. So the only way to make this task work is to inclcude the *jaxb* configuration+dependency to all projects using the task.

- Is it possible to make the task refer to the /buildSrc/build.gradle configuration classpath?
- Is it possible to avoid a dependency to jaxb-xjc from the projects *using* the task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## New solution

Actually while thinking about it, I found a better solution than my previous one with which I'm quite happy I think and which should not interfere in any way with the actual projects build.

In `build.gradle` of the `buildSrc` project:

```
configurations {
   wsimport
   xjc
}

dependencies {
   wsimport 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools:2.1.4'
   xjc 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.2.4-1'
}

def generatedResourcesDirectory = "$buildDir/resources/generated"

task generateClasspathsPropertiesFile {
   inputs.file configurations.wsimport
   inputs.file configurations.xjc
   def outputFile = file("$generatedResourcesDirectory/classpaths.properties")
   outputs.file outputFile
   doLast {
      def classpaths = new Properties()
      classpaths.wsimport = configurations.wsimport.asPath
      classpaths.xjc = configurations.xjc.asPath
      outputFile.parentFile.mkdirs()
      outputFile.withOutputStream { classpaths.store it, null }
   }
}

sourceSets.main.output.dir generatedResourcesDirectory, builtBy: generateClasspathsPropertiesFile
```

And then in the respective tasks:

```
class Xjc extends DefaultTask {
   ...

   @TaskAction
   def xjc() {
      ...

      def classpaths = new Properties()
      getClass().getResource('/classpaths.properties').withInputStream { classpaths.load it }
      ant.taskdef name: 'xjc', classname: 'com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask', classpath: classpaths.xjc
      ant.xjc ...

      ...
   }
}
```

---

```
class Wsimport extends DefaultTask {
   ...

   @TaskAction
   def wsimport() {
      ...

      def classpaths = new Properties()
      getClass().getResource('/classpaths.properties').withInputStream { classpaths.load it }
      ant.taskdef name: 'wsimport', classname: 'com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport', classpath: classpaths.wsimport
      ant.wsimport ...

      ...
   }
}
```

## Old solution

How I currently solve this kind of situation - although I'm not too happy with it - is having a Plugin besides the Task that needs to be applied:

```
class XjcPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
   static final CONFIGURATION_NAME = "xjc_${System.currentTimeMillis()}"

   @Override
   void apply(Project project) {
      project.configurations.create(CONFIGURATION_NAME) { visible: false }

      project.dependencies {
         "$CONFIGURATION_NAME" group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-xjc', version: '2.2.4-1'
      }
   }
}
```

---

```
class Xjc extends DefaultTask {
   ...

   @TaskAction
   def xjc() {
      if (!project.configurations.hasProperty(XjcPlugin.CONFIGURATION_NAME)) {
         throw new ConfigurationException("xjc configuration is missing on project ${project.name}, did you forget to apply XjcPlugin?")
      }
      ...
      def runClassPath = project.configurations."$XjcPlugin.CONFIGURATION_NAME".asPath
      ant.taskdef(name: 'xjc', classname: 'com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask', classpath: runClassPath)
      ant.xjc(...)
   }
}
```

But be aware that stuff like `configurations.all { ... }` or the `nebula-dependency-recommender-plugin` will also affect those configurations and may yield unexpected results.